# How to show all columns after performing GenomicRanges::subsetByOverlaps

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have the following two [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) objects. First one `gr1` is this:

```r
library(GenomicRanges)
set.seed(1)
gr1 <- GRanges(
        seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr1", "chr3"), c(1, 3, 2, 4)),
        ranges=IRanges(1:10, width=10:1, names=head(letters,10)),
        strand=Rle(strand(c("-", "+", "*", "+", "-")), c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2)),
        motif_score=seq(1, 0, length=10),
         motif_name=paste0("Motif_", toupper(sample(c(letters,letters))))[1:10]
      )
gr1
#> GRanges object with 10 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
#>     seqnames    ranges strand | motif_score  motif_name
#>        <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |   <numeric> <character>
#>   a     chr1  [ 1, 10]      - |   1.0000000     Motif_N
#>   b     chr2  [ 2, 10]      + |   0.8888889     Motif_S
#>   c     chr2  [ 3, 10]      + |   0.7777778     Motif_C
#>   d     chr2  [ 4, 10]      * |   0.6666667     Motif_S
#>   e     chr1  [ 5, 10]      * |   0.5555556     Motif_J
#>   f     chr1  [ 6, 10]      + |   0.4444444     Motif_Q
#>   g     chr3  [ 7, 10]      + |   0.3333333     Motif_R
#>   h     chr3  [ 8, 10]      + |   0.2222222     Motif_D
#>   i     chr3  [ 9, 10]      - |   0.1111111     Motif_B
#>   j     chr3  [10, 10]      - |   0.0000000     Motif_C
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

And the second object `gr2`:

```r
gr2 <- GRanges(seqnames="chr2", 
               ranges=IRanges(4:3, 6),
               peak_name=c("peak_1", "peak_2"),
               strand="+", peak_score=5:4)
gr2
#> GRanges object with 2 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
#>       seqnames    ranges strand |   peak_name peak_score
#>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>  <integer>
#>   [1]     chr2    [4, 6]      + |      peak_1          5
#>   [2]     chr2    [3, 6]      + |      peak_2          4
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

Then I perform the region overlap using [subsetByOverlaps](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GenoGAM/versions/1.0.2/topics/subsetByOverlaps%2CGenomicTiles%2CGRanges-method) between `gr1` and `gr2`

```r
 subsetByOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
#> GRanges object with 3 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
#>     seqnames    ranges strand | motif_score  motif_name
#>        <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |   <numeric> <character>
#>   b     chr2   [2, 10]      + |   0.8888889     Motif_S
#>   c     chr2   [3, 10]      + |   0.7777778     Motif_C
#>   d     chr2   [4, 10]      * |   0.6666667     Motif_S
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

as you can see the `peak_name` and `peak_score` column does not appear after intersection. How can I show them all?

Comment: `subsetByOverlaps` subsets features from `gr1` that overlap with `gr2`. In general (and in your case) `gr1` can overlap with multiple features from `gr2`; for example, `Motif_C` overlaps with `peak_1` and `peak_2`. So which `peak_name` and `peak_score` do you want to keep in the expected output? You can use `findOverlaps` plus `queryHits` and `subjectHits` to extract matching `gr1` and `gr2` features.

Comment: @MauritsEvers can you give example?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example based on your sample data below.

Answer (score 3):

First we find all overlaps of features in `gr1` (the query object) with features in `gr2` (the subject object).

```
# Find overlaps
m <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2);
```

We then store matching features in `gr1.matched`, and add metadata from `gr2`.

```
# Features from gr1 with overlaps in gr2
# Note: The same feature from gr1 can overlap with mulitple features from gr2
gr1.matched <- gr1[queryHits(m)];

# Add the metadata from gr2
mcols(gr1.matched) <- cbind.data.frame(
    mcols(gr1.matched),
    mcols(gr2[subjectHits(m)]));

gr1.matched;
#GRanges object with 6 ranges and 4 metadata columns:
#    seqnames    ranges strand | motif_score  motif_name   peak_name peak_score
#       <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |   <numeric> <character> <character>  <integer>
#  b     chr2   [2, 10]      + |   0.8888889     Motif_S      peak_2          4
#  b     chr2   [2, 10]      + |   0.8888889     Motif_S      peak_1          5
#  c     chr2   [3, 10]      + |   0.7777778     Motif_C      peak_2          4
#  c     chr2   [3, 10]      + |   0.7777778     Motif_C      peak_1          5
#  d     chr2   [4, 10]      * |   0.6666667     Motif_S      peak_2          4
#  d     chr2   [4, 10]      * |   0.6666667     Motif_S      peak_1          5
#  -------
#  seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```